# Anaconda, Spyder, Mayavi

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, spyder, mayavi

I'm using the anaconda distribution of python, and the spyder IDE.  Installing mayavi, via `conda install mayavi`, breaks spyder by downgrading numpy `1.10.4 -> 1.9.3` as seen via `conda list --revisions`.  I can 'fix' this problem by manually upgrading numpy again, but I suspect there will be issues with Mayavi.

**My question(s)**: Is there a better way to integrate Mayavi and spyder in anaconda?  And, more generally, is there a recommended protocol for managing package dependencies?  If installing mayavi hadn't broken the very next thing I used (spyder), it could have been quite difficult to track the source of this error.  Actually, I thought package management was the value proposition of, say, the anaconda distribution...

(Related but different question arises [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329149/spyder-together-with-mayavi).)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was using the same combinatation of tools.

The solution is to use [conda environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). Environments are independent 'spaces' where you can install particular combinations of packages independent of the 'main' set of packages that are there somewhere else. Detailed article [here](https://dziganto.github.io/data%20science/python/anaconda/Creating-Conda-Environments/)

The workflow would basically involve this:
Open Anaconda Prompt and setup a new conda environment for Mayavi ,eg. called 'mayavi_environment' :

```
conda create -n mayavi_environment python=(<PYTHONVERSION>)
```

where () is either 2.7,3.4 or which ever version you would like to create the environment with.

and once it's been created type :

```
activate mayavi_environment
```

Having done this then the necessary package dependencies need to be 
installed. I too had issues with spyder, and this was sorted out by completely uninstalling it and installing it afresh in the environment. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170468/how-to-run-spyder-in-virtual-environment) is a bunch of solutions to running spyder from the created environment.

Answer (score 0):

Installing mayavi is little bit complicated. It uses VTK, numpy==1.15.3 and traits lib which can't be compiled without VC2015. However you can find unofficial .whl files here:
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

There are some ways to manage these dependencies. You can use pipenv:
https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/

https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Or you can use conda environments of course. Above are alternatives.